# How to divide two doubles accurately

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, double

I have two

```
double a, b;
```

I know that the following is true

```
-1 <= a/b <= 1
```

however b can be arbitrarily small. When I do this naively and just compute the value

```
 a/b
```

the condition specified above does not hold in some cases and I get values like much greater than 1 in absolute value (like 13 or 14.)

How can I ensure that when I divide by b, I get a value such that the condition mentioned above can be enforced. In the case where I can not guarantee this I am happy to set the computed value a/b to 0.

Comment: When you say that -1 <= a/b <= 1, do you mean in theory or in practice? Might you already have roundoff errors in a and/or b before you do the division?

Comment: Please provide the actual numbers you're actually using to get the actual value of 13 or 14.

Comment: Are you dealing with subnormal numbers? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number)

Comment: If be can be arbitrarily small then a/b will be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to enforce is abs(a)≤abs(b). If that condition holds, then -1≤a/b≤1, regardless of floating-point precision used. Your logic error is occurring before the division, since at the division point abs(a)>abs(b) which violates your a-priori requirement.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with a and b before I even get to this step. I'm going to have to get back to you guys.

Comment: Ok so if anyone cares, the actual case of my error happened before I got to the division step and the condition abs(a)<=abs(b) was being broken before division.

Answer (score 10):

Division on an IEEE-754 system is a *correctly rounded* operation, which means that if no overflow or underflow occurs, the result will always be within 0.5 "ulp" of the mathematical "infinitely precise" result.  In non-FP-nerd speak, this means that the result will always be within a factor of about 2^-53 of the exact answer.  Since you know that the infinitely precise result is between -1 and 1, overflow cannot occur; underflow can, but that would result in numbers very, very near zero, not on the order of 13.

Either your condition does not actually hold, or you are on a system that does not have IEEE-754 arithmetic, or there is a bug in your code.  Can you post the values of a and b that are generating this result, and the code that you are using to do the division and print the result?

Comment: That's not strictly true.  The IEEE standard specifies a few different rounding modes, but your point is valid: division hardware (and software emulations) are accurate to within the precision available.  The problem here is lack of precision of the underlying representation, not a bad algorithm.

Comment: True. I'm assuming that a user who is (apparently) not particularly savvy about floating-point has probably not changed the rounding mode from the default. The rounding error in a non-default rounding mode can be as large as 1ulp, which is still fantastically smaller error than the error that the questioner is reporting.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely you're actually triggering data loss due to underflow.  While it is possible doubles have an incredible range and you're not likely to hit it.

I would think the problem lies somewhere before this.  You've either got a logic bug or you are simply eating up the available precision with a bunch of operations.  Be especially wary of additions and subtractions.  1E20 + 1 = 1E20.

If it's due to eating up the precision then you'll have to redesign your routine or resort to an arbitrary-precision library for your math.  (Beware--*SLOW*)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question, but if you are suggesting that -1 <= a/b <= 1 holds true for all real value a and b, this is definitely not the case.  Consider:

1 / 0.5 = 2

If you want to check whether the division will be within [-1, 1], why not just do the division and then act however you want when it falls between -1 and 1.

Comment: No, this is true of only the particular two numbers a and b. I'm getting inaccuracies because I'm dividing by a number that is much too small, smaller than machine precision. I need a way to check when I can guarantee the result us atmost a certain value from the true result.

Comment: The only number smaller than machine precision is 0. If you are not dividing by 0, then you are not dividing by a number smaller than machine precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test out your theory that this is a precision issue (though the other answers make it seem like you can't possibly be getting the results you're getting) you should be using GMP.  You already said you're "dividing by a number that is much too small, smaller than machine precision."  GMP's C++ bindings have arithmetic operators for everything and are actually kind of pleasant to use compared to the C bindings, [give them a try](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Floats.html)!

```
      mpf_class f(1.5);        // default precision
      mpf_class f(1.5, 500);   // 500 bits of precision (at least)
      double out = f.get_d();  // get a double out of an mpf_class
```

Answer (score 0):

The only situations I can think of where this would be true, are if `a/b` *should* be between -1 and 1, but is not, because both `a` and `b` are derived from calculations that make them very sensitive to floating-point errors.

For instance, if you try to calculate `b = 2-2*cos(theta)` and `a = theta*theta` for theta in radians, near zero, you will run into issues because the calculation of `b` involves the subtraction of numbers very close to 1, even though mathematically the answer is very close to 1.0 for small angles. (If I run the calculation of a/b for theta = 0.4e-7 using the Spidermonkey Javascript engine, I get 1.029 even though it really should be darned close to 1.0)

280Z28's answer is where you want to be, however without knowing more about how a and b are derived, and under what conditions you get undesirable results, it's hard to say what the best way is to ensure the calculations give meaningful numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You surely have some problem before you reach this point.  Regardless,  you can elimate that problem here if you are prepared to accept a 0 result.

```
float Calculate(float a, float b)
{
    if (abs(a) > abs(b))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return a/b;
    }
}
```

Comment: If -1 <= a/b <= +1 is theoretically satisfied but wrong in practice due to rounding errors, the OP might want to return +1 or -1 (depending on the signs of a and b) instead of 0.